# Systemctl doesn't run command which is perfectly executed in bash (back quote)

Tags: bash, docker, systemctl

The problem is that the result of executed command is not correctly passed in a systemctl service while executing such the command in bash is correct.

Here is my service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Java jar which listens to Redis
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker stop java_redis
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm java_redis
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name java_redis --rm java_redis:latest --redis_host `docker network inspect --format='{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}' bridge`
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop -t 2 java_redis

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The following command is executed without errors if I run in bash:

```
/usr/bin/docker run --name java_redis --rm java_redis:latest --redis_host `docker network inspect --format='{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}' bridge`
```

When I searched in journal , I noticed that the parameter is not pass correctly:

```
Oct 08 21:04:55 mscphisprk00034 docker[1328378]: No argument is allowed: network
Oct 08 21:04:55 mscphisprk00034 docker[1328378]: org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException: No argument is allowed: network
Oct 08 21:04:55 mscphisprk00034 docker[1328378]:         at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.parseArgument(CmdLineParser.java:509)
```

Could you please tell me how can I get that parameter in systemctl service?

I need to pass a parameter which is the result of the following command:

`docker network inspect --format='{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}' bridge`

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming-related question; sites like [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) might be better places to ask about systemctl unit files.  In general, the Docker-internal IP addresses aren't meant to be usable (and aren't reachable on non-Linux platforms) and I'd avoid the sorts of `docker inspect` lookups you show; you should be able to connect to `localhost` and the `docker run -p ???:6379` port number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the documentation for [`ExecStart=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) leads me to [Command Lines](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines), which specifies that only simple argument parsing are supported, one way around this is by wrapping your whole command line in a shell:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/docker run --name java_redis --rm java_redis:latest --redis_host "$(/usr/bin/docker network inspect --format="{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}" bridge)"'
```

Notice how I changed the inner single quotes to be double quotes to avoid the parser getting confused.

Just for good measure it would make sense to be consistent with your reference to `docker`, either write it as a full path or don't. Just avoid to mix the two references, eg either use `/usr/bin/docker` or use `docker`.

It's usually also preferable to use `$(...)` instead of the old-school `` `…` ``:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/docker run ... --redis_host $(/usr/bin/docker network ...)'
```

And remember to quote the expansion to avoid it undergoing word splitting and pathname expansion:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/docker run ... --redis_host "$(/usr/bin/docker network ...)"'
```